# symfony2 access $_SESSION from controller

Tags: javascript, symfony, session, session-variables

i set the session from javascript in my template twig so

```
sessionStorage.setItem('ids', ids);
```

how do I access $ _SESSION key value from controller?
i just try

```
$this->get('session')->get('ids')
```

without result

thanks!

Comment: Your question is an XY-problem: you should explain the real task, since the question as it is asked at the moment does not make much sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible.

`sessionStorage` is a temporary *client-side* storage and (default) symfony2 session storage is a temporary *server-side* storage.